# MITM attack, Replay Attack, TCP Session Hijacking

Tags: security, tcpip, session-hijacking

I was going over the internet reading about types of attacks on a computer system and I can not differentiate between MITM, Replay and TCP Session Hijacking.
They appear to be the same.
Sniff the data , change it , retransmit.
Please let me know if they are the same or different.

Comment: You might want to know about http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replay attacks and Session hijacking are two types of Man In The Middle attack.  MITM is the set, the other two are subsets.

You can be a man in the middle doing an attack on VoIP, some kinds of cryptography, etc.

Comment: `Replay attack`: capture , change , send
`TCP Hijacking`: capture , change , send.
Where do they differ then??

Comment: Fasih, they differ in what you are attacking.  TCP Session hijacking will ONLY hijack a TCP session.  A replay attack can be used against TCP, cryptography, etc...  A replay attack falls under the classification "Man In The Middle," just like a session hijack does.

Comment: OK so Replay can be retransmitting anything while TCP hijacking is ONLY retransmitting the TCP packets?

Comment: That is correct.